# Does the Tropo hosting service allow for including third party javascript libraries and using them from within the service?

Tags: javascript, tropo

I'm looking for an example or official documentation showing how to include a third party library as part of a Tropo hosted Javascript application for handling calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really won't find one. However, it appears that Tropo is using the JVM's scripting engine, which (for JavaScript) is based on Rhino. I'd expect you can just upload your third party library and then use Rhino's [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell#load%28.5Bfilename.2C_....5D%29) function to import it. You'll need to make sure your third party library doesn't depend on any global variables that don't exist (such as `window`,`document`, or pretty much any of the browser-specific objects that are out there) but that should work for you.

Comment: You (apparantly) cannot use `load` in Tropo.  Try this one line Tropo application: `say("load " + (typeof load == "undefined" ? "does not exist" : "exists"));`.  I heard "load does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

Tropo doesn't store your applications on the local filesystem, so any attempt to load a local file will fail. If you can import your file over http, that would work. Just reference the file using the same path you see as your application's URL in Tropo (the http://hosting.tropo.com... url).